# Initialize keycloack only for specific routes in angular 5

Tags: angular, routes, single-sign-on, angular5, keycloak

I am trying to add keycloack login only for some routes and other routes will be public. User can see the routes (pages).

By Default i am trying to load a public page and when a user try to submit details i have to ask him to login in

```
try {
  await keycloak.init({
    config: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
      realm: 'your-realm',
      clientId: 'client-id'
    },
    initOptions: {
      onLoad: 'login-required',
      checkLoginIframe: false
    },
    bearerExcludedUrls: [
      '/assets',
      '/clients/public'
    ],
  });
  resolve();
} catch (error) {}
```

but still its redirecting to keycloack login.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular
I had followed the documentation of above mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Route Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards).

Comment: i had updated my question. By Default i am trying to load a public page and when a user try to submit details i have to ask him to login in

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment keycloak init options "onLoad: 'login-required'". If keycloak starts with when application app starts, then you have to login when you open your app in browser. After commenting out onLoad, you have to login only when you enter url, which is behind AuthGuard.